# How do I best organize my development folder?

Tags: open-source, development-environment

I work on several development projects for multiple clients using various development tools and languages.  Over the years I've lost my ability to organize my development folder.  When I look at my development folder, it's just a big mess.

I've searched the .NET for best practices, but they are mostly about creating build scripts and the few discuss how to organize source trees, and those that do usually only concern themselves with one language.

Are there any ideas on how best to organize source trees using different tools, languages, and clients. Please bear in mind that some of the projects I work on are hybrids combining multiple languages.

Answer (score 2):

My workspace folder is like this:

```
/workspace
 /[client_name1]
  /project_name
   / - project structure depends on ide and language (.net, java, python)
 /[client_name2]
 /[company_name]
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally have subdirectories for each language, for my personal projects.
When having more than one client, I usually first create a client subdirectory, and in it each project (in case of many languages, first comes the language, then the project).

MYPROJECTS > Clients > Languages > Projects

In case of mixing more than one language in a project, I would do one of this:

-Use a language parent subdirectory for the main language the project uses

or

-Forget about the language classification and go directly to the Projects structure.

This works best for Clients projects. For MY projects (even though I may be a 'Client'), I insist in the Language classification, since I'm worried about the technologies used, and this structure lets me observe it at a glance...

Answer (score 1):

```
\dev\workspace4clientA\
    ...
    \workspace4clientB\projectX 
                      \projectY
                      \projectZ
                      -- project organization dependant on language and tools
    ...
    \workspace4clientC\
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

well I tried all of these, but things get hairy when you use more then one IDE/language/technology
for example I use flashBuilder, IntelliJ, and Sublime Text, Java/Javascript/actionscript so this approach mentioned above does not really fit the deal, also what about personal projects? and/or github projects, repositories? I am still looking for some good clever answer on this too...

Answer (score 0):

Well, at work we use this schema:

```
/devfolder
    /client1
         /projecttype
             /YYYYMMDD
```

For example:

```
/devfolder
    /client1
        /web-site
            /20140301
            /20140810
    /client2
        /app
            /20141012
```